# itextsharp PDF concatenation not working

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, asp.net-web-api2

i have a webapi where i have route to concatenate pdfs and return the byte array using memorystream

```
public HttpResponseMessage ConcatPDFs(string id, ICollection<int> pdfs) {

        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (Document doc = new Document())
        using (PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(doc, stream))
        {
            doc.Open();

            PdfReader reader = null;
            PdfImportedPage page = null;

            db.PDFForms.Where(p => pdfs.Contains(p.Id)).ToList().ForEach(file =>
            {
                var filePath = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/" + string.Format("Content/Uploads/PDFForms/")), file.FileName);
                reader = new PdfReader(filePath);

                for (int i = 0; i < reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    page = pdf.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
                    pdf.AddPage(page);
                }

                pdf.FreeReader(reader);
                reader.Close();
            });

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue(string.Format("{0}", "application/pdf"));
            return result;
        }
    }
```

this is my code, however when i stream the data back to the client the browser give me the error, failed to load pdf document. Any idea what i might be doing wrong? thank you.

Edit:

This works if i create a physical file and not use MemoryStream

Comment: Shot in the dark here...try releasing using doc.Close() prior to writing the stream.

Comment: when you say prior to writing to the stream, do you mean prior to result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray()); ?

Comment: wow amazing it worked. Thank you so much. I wonder why i have to close the doc before reading the bytes from the stream

Comment: *"I wonder why i have to close the doc before reading the bytes from the stream"* - Because upon closing the document the final data are written to the stream, in particular the cross reference table which must be at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can debug your application using wireshark?
Get the bytes from the response, paste them in a document and see whether that document can be read with something like Adobe Reader.

From the looks of it though, this does not seem like an iText issue, since you have confirmed that you can create a physical file.

So either it is the implementation of MemoryStream, or some other step that comes in between the creation of the document and sending the get response.

At any rate, I think the first step in solving this problem is storing the bytes you do get back, and comparing them against the physical file.